# Dell Optiplex 3010 - Upgrading CPU

Tags: processor, motherboard, desktop

I have a Dell Optiplex 3010.

I want to upgrade my CPU ,The motherboard is the Dell Inc. 042P49 (CPU 1) and currently has a Intel Core i3 2120 Socket 1155 LGA installed.

**I need the advice to choose the proper CPU compatible with my device to upgrade and also i want to know what is the maximum Generation that working well with my device etc 3th 4th 5th**

[image: CPU-Z Snapshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your motherboard is on [H61 Express Chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/52806).
- [List](http://ark.intel.com/products/52806#@compatibility) of compatible CPUs with your motherboard.
- Highest compatible generation working with your motherboard is **Ivy Bridge** (3rd generation).

I would choose between [i7 3770](http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/Intel-Core-i7-3770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) or [i5 3570](http://ark.intel.com/products/65702/Intel-Core-i5-3570-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz) it depends if you need more threads.

Comment: thanks for help but i see in CPUs list my cpu support Sandy Bridge 

Does in my case Ivy Bridge will work with me ?

Comment: @JustUser If this is exactly this motherboard it supports both Ivy and Sandy Bridge.

Comment: If you are thinking about gaming I would go with i5 because GPU is more important for gaming than i5 - i7 difference.

Comment: Please help me now i have purchased i7 3770 but when install it in my device not working my device not start what i can do right now does update bois can help me